# how to manage firebase authentication with redux toolkit along with email password and google?

Tags: javascript, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-toolkit

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    userName: null,
    userEmail: null
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setActiveUser: (state, action) => {
            state.userName = action.payload.userName
            state.userEmail = action.payload.userEmail
        },
        setUserLogOut: (state) => {
            state.userName = null
            state.userEmail = null
        }

    }
});

export const { setActiveUser, setUserLogOut } = userSlice.actions

export const selectUserName = state => state.user.userName
export const selectUserEmail = state => state.user.userEmail

export default userSlice.reducer
```

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared. Specifically: when you set a breakpoint on each line and run in the debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Although you have put your question into the post title, the post itself contains no text about details of your issue or expectations.  Please visit SO Help Center section on 'Asking' including the article on How to Ask a Good Question >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask